# What is the purpose of Manifest file

Tags: java

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html

What does a manifest file do?
What is the purpose of it?

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0

Name: java/math/BigDecimal.class
SHA1-Digest: TD1GZt8G11dXY2p4olSZPc5Rj64=
MD5-Digest: z6z8xPj2AW/Q9AkRSPF0cg==

Name: java/math/BigInteger.class
SHA1-Digest: oBmrvIkBnSxdNZzPh5iLyF0S+bE=
MD5-Digest: wFymhDKjNreNZ4AzDWWg1Q==
```

Does it update these classes in the jar automatically if there any changes in the server?

Comment: No, Its a metadata infomation, Suppose if you want to create a executable jar then manifest is used to specify start class of your application

Comment: The purpose of the manifest file is clearly explained in the page that you linked to, and there's no point us repeating it back to you.  Just, read it, try to understand it, and if you have specific questions, ask them in a new Question.

Comment: Think of it as a "table of contents" for the jar.

Comment: @StephenC Looks like he cannot grasp the explaination. I assume his "specific question" is that very same thing you're trying to tell him to go read again.

Answer (score 14):

**Manifest is a special file that can contain information about the files packaged in a JAR file**. By tailoring this **"meta"** information that the manifest contains, you enable the JAR file to serve a variety of purposes.

Mainfest file is mainly known for containing the name of the class that holds the main function, among various classes in the package...

When you create a JAR file, **it automatically receives a default manifest file. There can be only one manifest file in an archive**, and it always has the pathname

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

Answer (score 9):

> What does a manifest file do? What is the purpose of it?

The purpose is to hold metadata about the JAR file and the classes that it contains.  The metadata is used for a variety of things, including tracking the origin of the JAR, protecting against tampering, and providing the extra  information needed for an *executable* JAR.

The link in your question is broken.  Here are a couple of alternatives:

- [Working with Manifest Files: The Basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html)
- [JAR File Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html)

> Does it update these classes in the jar automatically if there any changes in the server?

No.

Those entries are *part* of a scheme for detecting tampering with JAR files; e.g. someone replacing those classes with modified versions.  (The other parts of the scheme are a digital signature of the hashes, and stuff in the launcher that checks the signatures and hashes before launching.)

Answer (score 4):

Manifest file provides the meta data for a file. The meta data is in form of name-value pairs. In your above example they have provided the MD5 hash of the class file which is calculated without the manifest file. This is a security measure so that if someone modifies the file and adds some hackish code, you can detect it with the signatures.

It plays no role in updating the file.

Answer (score -1):

The manifest is a specific no-class file assembled within a Jar, which contains the descriptive pairs of keys and values of this Jar and we usually called it metadata, it tells end users or callers:

> what the propose of Jar?   who is the writer?   when it was created?  what is creation env? what is JDK version? and even more...(Assuming have these values in manifest)

Answer (score -1):

A Manifest File plays very important role in streaming media content. Because it is the one file which tells subscriber end devices what about the streaming content is.

This manifest file contains **Resolution of content**, **Codecs** of content and **adaptive bitrate**.

If still you wants to understand it in details then you can visit this brief article which will make your all confusion clear : [What Is Manifest File Explain In Details with Diagram](https://www.headendinfo.com/manifest-file/)

Comment: The question is about the Manifest file of a java archive(jar).