# In Manifest file and Application class in an APK, which is called first?

Tags: android, manifest

I have read that Application class is the first one to execute and launching APK. But Application component is mentioned in Manifest file.
When Manifest file is called?

Comment: The manifest is not executable code, so it is not "called". It's read, however, many times, the first being upon installation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add name attribute to the application tag of your manifest file manually, which points to a file extends Application. Eg below.

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication" //Path to you Application java file  
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/icon_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

MyApplication.java

```
package com.sample;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static final String TAG = "MyApplication";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG,"Application onCreate");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every app project must have an AndroidManifest.xml file (with precisely that name) at the root of the [project source set](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html#sourcesets). The manifest file describes essential information about your app to the Android build tools, the Android operating system, and Google Play.

If you're using Android Studio to build your app, the manifest file is created for you, and most of the essential manifest elements are added as you build your app (especially when using [code templates](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/templates.html)).

[I would recommend you to check these Guides](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro)

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11410072/5792379) maybe helpful too.